# I would like to load csv file and catch an exception if any of the rows are empty

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class BadData(ValueError):
    pass

class CSVReader():

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def row_to_record(row):
        try:
            row == 0
        except BadData:
            print("Found an empty row")
        fileList = []
        fileList = fileList + row
        return fileList

    def load():
        with open('laliga.csv', mode='r'): 
            csvfilereader = csv.reader(csvfile) 
            for row in csvfilereader:
                row_to_record(row)

obj1 = CSVReader('laliga.csv')
obj1.load()
```

The objective of this program is to first load the csv file and then send each row from this file into the row_to_record method. Here I validate and see if any rows are empty. If they are empty then I raise my own custom exception class called Bad Data.

The Laliga.csv file contains the following rows:

No  Team    MP  W   D   L   F   A   D   P   Last 5 matches

1   Real Madrid 29  22  5   2   78  30  48  71  WWWWW

2   Barcelona   30  21  6   3   88  26  62  69  WWWLW

3   Atlético Madrid 30  18  7   5   55  23  32  61  WWWWW

4   Sevilla 30  17  7   6   52  37  15  58  LDLDD

5   Villarreal  30  14  9   7   42  23  19  51  WLLWW

Edit:Adding a link to file..https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11XCesWFl-gvm7j0SU2CJQZ2QVEiDK4-iKj3FKFC0LDo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: 1. This is not valid csv format 2. what is the actual question here?

Comment: Can you post a link to the actual file where the data is coming in? The separator doesn't look right. Perhaps the fields are separated with tabs?

Comment: @hashemi ...just added the link

Answer (score 0):

```
class BadData(Exception):
    pass

class CSVReader(object):

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def row_to_record(row):
        fileList = []
        fileList = fileList + row
        return fileList

def load():
        with open('laliga.csv', mode='r'): 
            csvfilereader = csv.reader(csvfile) 
            for row in csvfilereader:
                if not row:
                    raise BadData('Row not found!')
                row_to_record(row)

obj1 = CSVReader('laliga.csv')
try:
    obj1.load()
except BadData:
    print "Found an empty row!"
```

You were close! What you want to do is raise the exception as soon as you notice it. This happens in "load" when you encounter an empty row.

Note that I made a few changes:

1. It's good practice for your exceptions to inherit from the normal "Exception" class
2. You should also have your CSVReader inherit from something. The default answer is "object". This is called using new-style classes, and you can find more info about it [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass)
3. Right now it seems like your "row_to_record" function isn't really doing anything. If your job is to only find empty rows you could do it without the row_to_record function even existing.

Comment: Hey...thanks for the awesome explanation. I actually plan to add some more functionality to row_to_record function.

Comment: Absolutely, happy to help. Hope it works for you! Don't forget to mark accepted if it's what you were looking for